# Is use of position:absolute inside relative can create problems in Print ,screen-readers and for mobile users?

Tags: css, printing, accessibility, screen-readers

Is use of `position:absolute` inside `relative` can create problems in Print ,screen-readers and for mobile users?

or `float` + `margin` + `Padding` is still best if we need good compatibility at Screen, Printing and for screen reader and mobile users, Should i less use `Position`?

Comment: Not sure what is best for accessibility and things like screen readers and printing, but I know from personal experience that relatively positioned elements inside fixed positioned elements have given me a lot of grief in the past and are probably best if you can avoid them completely.

Comment: Why would screen readers care about the `position` property?

Answer (score 2):

Screen readers completely ignore the positioning of elements via CSS. They instead use the order the elements appear in the DOM when deciding what to read first.

Consider the following example:

```
<p style="position:absolute;top:100;left:0">Foo</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0">Bar</p>
```

Visually, the "Bar" paragraph appears first, because we've positioned it above the other using CSS. But the screen reader will ignore the CSS and just read the "Foo" paragraph followed by the "Bar" paragraph.

So to answer your question, yes it's probably fine for screen reader users. However, be aware of the ordering of your elements and make sure that the page still makes sense when read in that order.

For position:fixed, it will depend on your target browsers. IE6 for example, doesn't support "fixed" positioning. Most mobile phones don't either (definitely mobile Safari doesn't on the iPhone) due to the fact that the viewport is of limited size.

Comment: What gets sent to the printer is "generally" what is displayed on the screen visually, although browsers will often ignore certain CSS properties (like background colours, images) to save ink, and apply wrapping to make sure things fit on the printed page.

If you'd like to customize how your page looks when printed, definitely investigate the media="print" attribute on the link tag. That will let you include specific CSS only when the page is being printed. A List Apart has a good article on this technique:
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/.